# Where "python pip install" command files to be installed?

Tags: python, windows, pip

I install some packages with pip command and when use `pip freeze` command shows some packages that is install

```
pip freeze

antlr4-python3-runtime==4.5.2.1
django==1.9.4
django-realtime==1.1
pymssql==2.1.2
```

I want to know where is location of this modules in **Windows** ?

I installed them with: `python setup.py install`

I search in python`s installation directory but not found anything

Comment: See [Finding modules](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#finding-modules).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#finding-modules) in python documentation:

> Python usually stores its library (and thereby your site-packages folder) in the installation directory. So, if you had installed Python to C:\Python\, the default library would reside in C:\Python\Lib\ and third-party modules should be stored in C:\Python\Lib\site-packages.

If you want to install your packages in a different directory, use:

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=$PREFIX_PATH" package_name
```

Use can use also `--ignore-installed` to force all dependencies to be reinstalled.

see other [options](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/?highlight=install-option#options)

Answer (score 0):

Having installed modules using pip on windows, they should be in the installation directory, in `"Lib/site-packages"` directory.
So suppose you have installed Python at

> C://python27_x64

then those modules should be at

> C://python27_x64/Lib/site-packages/